# R - How to pass an expression to a cluster (in the parallel package)

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to create a parallelized version of replicate on top of the parallel package. An issue I'm running into is that it keeps evaluating my expressions before handing them to the replicate function, reproducible code:

```
par_replicate <- function(cl, n, expr){
    parallel::clusterCall(
        cl = cl,
        function() replicate(n , expr)
    )
}

cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2)
par_replicate(cl, 3, rnorm(1))
stopCluster(cl)

[[1]]
[1] -1.312669 -1.312669 -1.312669

[[2]]
[1] 0.5598533 0.5598533 0.5598533
```

As you can see the expression is evaluated within the cluster before its given to the replicate function thus replicate just returns multiple copies of the same number. I am at a complete loss for how to solve this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This works. You just need to cut `n` in `ncores` parts.

Comment: You should look at the `future_replicate()` function of package {future.apply}.

Answer (score 0):

Encase anyone was interested in the answer I managed to fix this using the `match.call()` and `eval()` functions:

```
par_replicate <- function(cl, n, expr){
    x <- match.call()
    parallel::clusterCall(
        cl = cl,
        function() replicate(n , eval(x$expr))
    )
}

cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2)
par_replicate(cl, 3, {rnorm(1)})
stopCluster(cl)
```

Not sure if this is the best solution but it seems to work for me :)

Comment: Note that, for sound statistical results, one needs to make sure to use parallel random number generation (RNG), cf. `?parallel::nextRNGStream` (L'Ecuyer RNG).  The `future.apply::future_replicate()` function uses that L'Ecuyer RNG framework. (disclaimer: I'm the author of [future.apply](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future.apply)).  PS. You can use it with your existing cluster; just set `future::plan(cluster, workers = cl)` first.